# Set style to all classes starting with "mark-as-" dynamically in angular 2

Tags: css, angular

I would like to be able to set dynamically in my component, whether or not an element with a class name that starts with "mark-as" (e.g "mark-as-car", "mark-as-cat") will have a yellow background.

I can add the following to the component css file:

```
*[class^="mark-as-"] {
background: #ffff00;
}
```

But I would like to know how to enable/disable it dynamically in the component logic without changing the elements class names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below css approach.

You can visit [css selectors](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) for more knowledge of css selectors.

```
[class*="mark-as-"] {
background: #ffff00;
}
```

Below an example to make more understandable.

```css
.mark-as-red {
  color:#fff;
}

.yellow-mark {
  color:#fff;
}


p[class*="-as-red"] {
background: #999;
}

p[class^="yellow-"] {
background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p class="mark-as-red ">
HELLO
</p>

<p class="yellow-mark ">
HELLO
</p>
```

Comment: thanks for answering, i've updated my question to make it more clearer.